# Polymer application filtering data from a sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, polymer, filtering

Is there anyone who has experience using Polymer?

What I have:
A sqlite database storing an array data with some objects inside. 
A polymer app displaying the objects from the database using the dom-repeat web component.

What I need to do:
Displaying from the database only those objects based on a filtering.

In my app I have a "filter" form with some options to be checked, and depending on which option gets checked (they are checkboxes), it should return only those objects from the database that match my selection.

I know you can use the a "filter" element in the dom-repeat component that accepts a value which is a callback function. And in the app to check if an option has been checked we can insert checked="{{hostChecked::change}}". From the Polymer documentation I also know that you can insert observers to look for changes in the app. I got this far, but can't manage to figure out how to put all these findings together.

I'm pretty knew to Polymer and an experience help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<my-app>
  <my-checkbox checked="{{prop1}}">
  <my-checkbox checked="{{prop2}}">
  ...
</my-app>
```

then:

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    prop1: Boolean,
    prop2: Boolean,
    filter: {
      computed: '_computeFilter(prop1, prop2,...)'
    }
  };
}

_computeFilter(prop1, prop2,...) {
  return function(item) {
    return (item.prop1 === prop1 && item.prop2 === prop2 && ...)
  }
}
```

and:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sqldata}}" filter="{{filter}}">
```

As I understand you're more concerned about changes to the app checkboxes than to sqldata changing at runtime.

Comment: Hi Lukasz, thanks for the quick help. The console is giving syntaxerror:unexpected token get. Does the static get properties have to go inside of a new class, like `class XCustom extends Polymer.Element {

    static get properties() {
      return {
        user: String,
        manager: {
          type: Boolean,
          notify: true
        }
      }
    }
` ?

Comment: They should go into the class that implements the filter and the list view, specifically in the example I gave it would be `class MyApp extends Polymer.Element`

    <my-app>
      <my-checkbox checked="{{prop1}}">
      <my-checkbox checked="{{prop2}}">
      ...
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sqldata}}" filter="{{filter}}">
    </my-app>

Comment: What if I am using a dom-module to create the app? Is it still going to be the same?